# 2d array find sum of row in cpp

Tags: c++

I want to calculate the sum of each row in a 2d array.
I'm not sure what I need to add in order to calculate the sum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int rows = 3;
const int cols = 4;

int main(){

    int arrayList[rows][cols]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    int total;
    int sum;

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        cout << endl;
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
            cout << setw(5) << arrayList[i][j];
            cout << sum;
        }       
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "total of all integers is: " << total << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I figured I have to add something in the nested `for` loop. I want to show the sum of each row after the elements of row is printed.

Comment: Why you ask 3d and you have 2d array in code

Comment: Please have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Just perform the sum in the loop on columns and reset it at the beginning of loop on rows.

```
int arrayList[rows][cols]= {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
int total = 0;
int sum;

for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
    cout << endl;
    sum = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
       cout << setw(5) << arrayList[i][j] << endl;
       sum += arrayList[i][j];
    }
    total += sum;
    cout << sum << endl;
}

cout << endl;
cout << "total of all integers is: " << total << endl;
```

Comment: logically thats correct but when i compile my code i get a the array *10 as output and sum is not displayed.

Comment: Can I have the explanation of the person who downvoted?

Comment: Isn't it. I added the computation of total by the way.

Comment: i realised what you did to get your code running
.i would love to excel in coding but i dont know how i should structure my studying for coding.

Comment: Your problem here was more *algorithm conception* than *coding*. You just need to train for that.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but perhaps you should mention that this is not the coding style one should normally use in C++. And also add a couple words of explanation.

Comment: Yep, std::vector or std::array could be used instead, but C-style arrays do also work and perform well so why not.

Comment: There may be performance reasons for using C-style arrays, also coding with MPI may be a good reason. On the other hand C++ containers like vectors in the background give you things like successful allocation checking which you would need to explicitly program when using C arrays. That given that in a regular code you won't be making all your arrays statically allocated. With C++ containers you can use features like generic algorithms in a more elegant way. There is even a function for a [sum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) of vector elements.

Comment: That function will reduce this program by 80% or so. Which is important for long programs. In principle, with C++ containers you can use the full functionality of the language in a most elegant/readable way possible.

Comment: @atru: I agree but the problem here is an algorithmic problem. So if I give an answer using high-level functions, the problem could be masked.

Comment: I totally agree with you on this one. I'm just thinking that maybe commenting on the other options and proper habits would be good, and that that might have been the reason for a downvote. Though one never knows for sure :)